# How to create multi site on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, web, content-management-system

I want to create somethink like [this](https://www.vogels.com). But i don't know how exactly to do it. As you can see, we have multilingual and multicontent site (btutton at the top of site). 
First decision it's create two folders in main domain directory and install two different sites. But i think it's not good idea, because it would be to hard manage this sites. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a multisite using [Wordpress Network](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) .

Comment: Thanks, may be you knowe some other way?

Comment: @Vlad sorry for the late response, but if you're just trying to make a multilingual site with the same content you can use a multilingual plugin like [Bogo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bogo/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a multi site is the way to go. Multi sites are useful when you have multiple sites that use the same styling, plugins, custom PHP, etc but unique content. Typically, multi sites each have their own domain.

It depends a little bit on how distinct you want your two sub-sites to be, but if you're trying to replicate the Vogel's website, I would suggest you just create a few extra pages for your unique content. If you look at the Vogel's site, the consumer/professional toggle is essentially just a link to two different landing pages. You can easily save the choice that users make via cookies so they always see that page as the homepage in the future.

For the multilingual aspect, you can use a plugin like [WPML](https://wpml.org/) to take care of that for you. It really isn't necessary to build an entirely new site unless you expect everything (including styling, plugins, etc) to be completely different.

Comment: Customer wants there same site. So two questions how to do it and how do it correct.

Comment: How to do which part? For setting up multiple languages, there are any number of plugins that you can use for that, including my suggestion of WPML. You can follow their documentation for configuring the plugin once it's installed in WordPress. For the dynamic content aspect of the site, the best way to proceed really depends on what kind of content and how much content needs to be unique. Either way, you'll probably end up using cookies, which you can read about [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).